# Java files instead of jar files in my downloaded java package?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

The joml java package I downloaded to import into eclipse to use in my project contains all java files instead of jar files. The problem is you cant import java files, you have to import jar files of course. Am I missing something important. I downloaded this package right off Github. I placed the java file I need which is (vector3f )into my library but still cant import it.

I've tried looking into the problem and found nothing. Ive leaned that a jar file is multiple java files put into one. I've also learned you cant make a jar file by compiling and running your project in cmd, but with this being a package they should already be jar files plus there is no public static void main to run it. Has anyone had this problem before

Comment: Got a link to the project you downloaded?

Comment: You mean to the package? https://github.com/JOML-CI/JOML

Comment: What about the actual file/link you downloaded?

Comment: I think that's the same one I have used.  Yes, you only get source files.  You'll have to build the project yourself.  Most IDEs will recognize the `pom.xml` build file and create the project for you.  You can then add the result to your own project as a Jar file (or sometimes you can add the project directly as a supporting library).